# How can I execute OS Commands with Python pexpect?

Tags: python, linux, shell, operating-system, command

I want to execute a python script, which switches to another user by automatically writing the user password. Both users have no root rights. After the login I want to execute the OS Commands "whoami" to check if the login was successful. Here's the code:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('su - otheruser)
child.expect_exact('Password:')
child.sendline('password')
print("logged in...")
child.expect('')
child.sendline('whoami')
print(child.before)
```

I want to print the output from the command to the console (just for debugging) but the output is like "b272' (a combination of random letters) and not the actual whoami user. How can I fix that?

Later I want to create from the switched user some files and so on. So basically, I want to execute OS Commands in a python script which is logged in an other user.

Answer (score 0):

Pexpect searches are not greedy, so it will stop at the first match. When I tested your code with `before`, `match.groups()`, `after`, and `buffer`, I didn't get an `EOF` or `TIMEOUT`, so it must have matched right at the beginning of the read and returned nothing (I'm surprised you got any results at all).

I recommend always following a `sendline` with an `expect`, and the end of a prompt (`]$`) is a good thing to expect, instead of an empty string.

Here is my take on your code, including creating a file:

> **NOTE** - Tested on Centos 7.9, using Python 2.7.

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("su - orcam")
child.expect_exact("Password:")
child.sendline("**********")
child.expect_exact("]$")
print("Logged in...\n")
child.sendline("whoami")
child.expect_exact("]$")
print(child.before + "\n")
child.sendline("echo -e 'Hello, world.' >> hello.txt")
child.expect_exact("]$")
child.sendline("cat hello.txt")
child.expect_exact("]$")
print(child.before + "\n")
child.sendline("exit")
index = child.expect_exact(["logout", pexpect.EOF, ])
print("Logged out: {0}".format(index))
```

**Output:**

```
Logged in...

 whoami
orcam
[orcam@localhost ~

 cat hello.txt
Hello, world.
[orcam@localhost ~

Logged out: 0
```